# Where with exists how it works in subselect with variable without link

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

I have a question about the `EXISTS` clause: I have a query using it, but with code I have never seen.

In the `WHERE` of subselect, I see this expression:

```
WHERE 
    @var IS NULL 
    OR EXISTS(another subselect)
```

But this variable cannot do link with his select and subselect.

How does this work?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. This means it will return all the rows if @var is null or there are any rows returned in the exists subquery.

Comment: *this variable cannot do link* - not sure what that means, the variable is nothing to do with the `exists` clause (which you have omitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where @var is null` is a boolean condition

if `@var` is null, then it's true - else false.

```
or exists (select '' from table t 
           where t.id = s.id and date > '2012-12-1')
```

returns true, if at least one row exists for the subquery.

If `@var` is not null, then `exists` is evaluated for a true condition

Comment: Thank you!
But the variable need to do "join" with the main query?